# Bash Appened character to beginging of Line that matches IP address in another file

Tags: bash, sed, grep

I have two files.

In the the first file it is full of ip addresses, 
In the second file i am looking to find all the matches of those IP addreses.
I then want to append to the front of the line that IP is located on in the second file with a character # and overwrite the file (second).

It seems like all the / are causing my issue but i am unsure

```
file1.txt
10.148.88.137

file2.txt
#
# Accounting file(s)
#
<acct-file /var/log/pmta/acct.csv>
    delete-after                30d
    move-interval               5m
    max-size                    50M
    records                     d
    record-fields               d timeLogged,bounceCat,vmta,orig,rcpt,srcMta,dlvSourceIp,jobId,dsnStatus,dsnMta,dsnDiag,header_x-id
</acct-file>

<acct-file /var/log/pmta/bounce.csv>
    delete-after                30d
    move-interval               5m
    max-size                    50M
    records                     b,rb
    record-fields               b timeLogged,bounceCat,vmta,orig,rcpt,srcMta,dlvSourceIp,jobId,dsnStatus,dsnMta,dsnDiag,header_x-id
    record-fields               rb *,header_x-id
</acct-file>

############################################################################################
############################### Global Domain Directive ####################################

<domain *>
    backoff-retry-after              15m
    backoff-to-normal-after          1m
    bounce-after                     72h
    bounce-upon-5xx-greeting         true
    dkim-algorithm                   rsa-sha256                      
    dkim-body-canon                  simple                          
    dkim-sign                        yes    
    ignore-8bitmime                  true
    ignore-chunking                  yes   
    max-connect-rate                 10/m
    max-msg-per-connection           450
    max-msg-rate                     60/m
    max-rcpt-per-message             100
    max-smtp-out                     5
    mx-connection-attempts           10
    require-starttls                 no                              
    retry-upon-new-mail              true
    smtp-553-means-invalid-mailbox   yes
    smtp-pattern-list                blockList
    use-starttls                     yes
</domain>

smtp-listener 10.148.88.137
smtp-listener 10.148.1.137

##################################################################################################

# EOF    

File 2 Overwritten (file2.txt)
#
# Accounting file(s)
#
<acct-file /var/log/pmta/acct.csv>
    delete-after                30d
    move-interval               5m
    max-size                    50M
    records                     d
    record-fields               d timeLogged,bounceCat,vmta,orig,rcpt,srcMta,dlvSourceIp,jobId,dsnStatus,dsnMta,dsnDiag,header_x-id
</acct-file>

<acct-file /var/log/pmta/bounce.csv>
    delete-after                30d
    move-interval               5m
    max-size                    50M
    records                     b,rb
    record-fields               b timeLogged,bounceCat,vmta,orig,rcpt,srcMta,dlvSourceIp,jobId,dsnStatus,dsnMta,dsnDiag,header_x-id
    record-fields               rb *,header_x-id
</acct-file>

############################################################################################
############################### Global Domain Directive ####################################

<domain *>
    backoff-retry-after              15m
    backoff-to-normal-after          1m
    bounce-after                     72h
    bounce-upon-5xx-greeting         true
    dkim-algorithm                   rsa-sha256                      
    dkim-body-canon                  simple                          
    dkim-sign                        yes    
    ignore-8bitmime                  true
    ignore-chunking                  yes   
    max-connect-rate                 10/m
    max-msg-per-connection           450
    max-msg-rate                     60/m
    max-rcpt-per-message             100
    max-smtp-out                     5
    mx-connection-attempts           10
    require-starttls                 no                              
    retry-upon-new-mail              true
    smtp-553-means-invalid-mailbox   yes
    smtp-pattern-list                blockList
    use-starttls                     yes
</domain>

#smtp-listener 10.148.88.137
smtp-listener 10.148.1.137

##################################################################################################

# EOF
```

Thanks for your help in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***EDIT:*** Since OP has changed Input_file2 so adding solution according to it now.

```
awk 'FNR==NR{a[$0];next} match($0,/[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+/) && substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH) in a{$0="#"$0} 1'  Input_file1  Input_file2 > temp_file  &&  mv temp_file  Input_file2
```

Adding a non-one liner form of above solution now.

```
awk '
FNR==NR{
   a[$0]
   next
}
prev!=FILENAME{
     close(out)
     System("mv " out OFS prev)
}
match($0,/[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+/) && substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH) in a{
   $0="#"$0
}

{
    prev=FILENAME
    out=prev".temp"
    print $0 > out
}
END{
    close(out)
    system("mv " out OFS prev)
}
'  Input_file  Input_file2
```

---

---

Could you please try following.

```
awk '
FNR==NR{
  a[$0]=$0
  next
}
($2 in a){
  $0="#"$0
}
1
'  Input_file1  Input_file2 > tmp_file && mv tmp_file Input_file2
```

Comment: @Dennis, it worked for me fine, could you please check once if you have any control M characters in your file? by doing `cat -v Input_file` once and let me know then?

Comment: i updated the File above and it fails on that but works otherwise, could i be failing due to the / in the files?

Comment: @Dennis, this is fully different from what you posted previously. Please do mention more correctly, expected output and file2 is NOT at all clear.

Comment: Apologies didn't realize it would be an issue as what i really am looking to do is find a matching IP address from one file in the other and add a # to the beginning of the line it is on

Comment: @Dennis, np, please try my EDIT code and let me know then?

Comment: That worked , thank you so much for your patience and help. I will mark this as correctly answered now

Comment: Is it the same process if i have a File 3 (it contains IPS as well) and i want to remove the # before the smtp-listener if that IP is found in file 3

Comment: @Dennis, no this changes specifically 2nd file, though, you could try to print new values(hashed ones). If  you have latest version of `gawk` then you could try like `gawk -i inplace` but we need may need to change this commnd.

Comment: I am using CentOS 6 so i am locked into GNU Awk 3.1.7.

Comment: I am almost sleeping as of now. I edited my EDIT answer's non-one liner form answer bug NOT tested so test it for test file ones and let me know. Will check SO in few hours or so, cheers.

Comment: Appreciate all your help i did get an error though

#!/bin/bash
awk '
FNR==NR{
   a[$0]
   next
}
prev!=FILENAME{
     close(out)
     System("mv " out OFS prev)
}
match($0,/[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+/) && substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH) in a{
   $0="#"$0
}

{
    prev=FILENAME
    out=prev".temp"
    print $0 > out
}
END{
    close(out)
    system("mv " out OFS prev)
}
'  file1.txt  file2.txt


[root@serv2-www home]# sh a.sh
awk: cmd. line:8: (FILENAME=file2.txt FNR=1) fatal: function `System' not defined

Comment: Oh sorry typed from mobile. It should be small s there.

Comment: So changing that to a lowercase S allowed it to run but it generates another error, "mv: missing file operand"
Also and again i apologize for not understand enough but where do i put file3.txt in this? Thank you for all your help.

Answer (score 0):

if 1st file contains IPs only, listed each one on one line, try gnu sed,

```
sed -Ez 's/\n/\|/g; s!(.*)\|!s/^\\w.+(\1)/# \\1/!' file1.txt| sed -Ef - file2.txt
```